# Add seperate jniLibs reference for different module dependencies in Android Studio project

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am developing an android project with two different module dependencies:

1. A third party jar dependency.
2. An Android Library dependency that I have created myself.

Both of these modules are using different C++ libraries. The jar dependency refers to its libraries `/ .so` files itself.

I have only added it to my project as a jar dependency. However, for android library dependency I have added the `.so` files in the `libs/armeabi-v7a/` folder and have added their reference in module level `build.gradle` file as follows:

```
android {
 defaultConfig {

        ndk {
            abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a'
        }
    }


    sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }
    }
}
```

Without adding this code to my android library dependency's `build.gradle` file, the `.so` files are not included in the build and I get an error when I try to load `.so` files. On the other hand, the jar dependency throws an error when it tries to refer to its own `.so` files when I add the above mentioned code in my android library dependency's `build.gradle`.

I have googled this issue and haven't found anything. Is there a way to reference the jniLibs directory module wise to resolve this sort of clash?

Comment: Please share error log when you add the ndk related blocks in build.gradle

Comment: @aminography I don't get any eror when I add ndk related block in build.gradle! When I run it with the ndk block the app just gets stuck on System.LoadLibrary(".so filename")

Comment: @aminography When this line of code is executed for the third party .jar dependency actually.

Answer (score 0):

this can be accomplished by repackaging the 3rd party `.jar`:

- do not set the (C) `jniLibs` path to the (Java) `libs` directory.
- but extract (and remove) the `.so` native libraries from the `.jar` (it's `.zip` format)
- and then drop them into `jniLibs/armeabi`.

Comment: I have already tried putting so files in armeabi and armeabi-v7a directories. Also extracted the .jar to get the so file and added it manually but it doesn't work.